# SetWindowsHookEx - WH_MOUSE callback is triggered twice for WM_LBUTTONDOWN

Tags: excel, vsto, hook, mouse, setwindowshookex

In an VSTO Excel Add-In I need to render content in the crosstab of an worksheet when specific coordinates in the crosstab are clicked (and remove the content again, when the same coordinates are clicked again).

Therefore I am using a MouseProc callback function which is registered via SetWindowsHookEx:

```cs
    _hMouseHook = WinApi.SetWindowsHookEx(WinApi.WH_MOUSE, _mouseHookProcedure,
                  WinApi.GetModuleHandle(module.ModuleName), (int)WinApi.GetCurrentThreadId());
```

Unfortunately it seems like Excel is misbehaving and triggers each WM_LBUTTONDOWN and WM_LBUTTONUP message twice (and probably also other messages).

This is how the MouseProc callback looks like:

```cs
    private int MouseHookProcedure(int nCode, Int32 wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
      if (nCode == WinApi.HC_ACTION)
      {
        var mouseHookStruct = (MouseHookStruct)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(MouseHookStruct));
        WinApi.WindowMessage message = (WinApi.WindowMessage)wParam;

        if (message == WinApi.WindowMessage.WM_LBUTTONDOWN)
        {
          Debug.WriteLine($"WH_MOUSE_Hook: WM_LBUTTONDOWN - nCode:{nCode} WParam:{wParam} LParam:{lParam} X:{mouseHookStruct.pt.X}  Y:{mouseHookStruct.pt.Y} " +
                          $"Handle:{(IntPtr)mouseHookStruct.hwnd}  Message:{message} HitTestCode:{mouseHookStruct.wHitTestCode} ExtraInfo:{mouseHookStruct.dwExtraInfo}");
        }
        else if (message == WinApi.WindowMessage.WM_LBUTTONUP)
        {
          Debug.WriteLine($"WH_MOUSE_Hook: WM_LBUTTONUP - nCode:{nCode} WParam:{wParam} LParam:{lParam} X:{mouseHookStruct.pt.X}  Y:{mouseHookStruct.pt.Y} " +
                          $"Handle:{(IntPtr)mouseHookStruct.hwnd}  Message:{message} HitTestCode:{mouseHookStruct.wHitTestCode} ExtraInfo:{mouseHookStruct.dwExtraInfo}");
        }
      }

      try
      {
        // event not handled, call next Hook to process / delegate event
        return WinApi.CallNextHookEx(_hMouseHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
      }
      catch
      {
        return 0;
      }
    }
```

I also know that the behavior can be different on some Excel installations so that the WM_LBUTTONDOWN message sometimes is only sent a single time. And unfortunately I don't know the reason for the varying behavior of Excel.

It works fine when using Subclassing instead of a hook but unfortunately this is no alternative because Subclassing caused compatibility issues with other add-ins which also use it.

I created a small test VSTO Add-In which demonstrates the issue by logging the events to the console:

> WH_MOUSE_Hook: WM_LBUTTONDOWN - nCode:0 WParam:513 LParam:55637568 ...
>   WH_MOUSE_Hook: WM_LBUTTONDOWN - nCode:0 WParam:513 LParam:55637568 ...
>   Subclassing: WM_LBUTTONDOWN - WParam:1 LParam:17957938 Message:513 ...
>   WH_MOUSE_Hook: WM_LBUTTONUP - nCode:0 WParam:514 LParam:55633504 ...
>   WH_MOUSE_Hook: WM_LBUTTONUP - nCode:0 WParam:514 LParam:55633504 ...

Is there something wrong with my code which could explain this behavior? Or did somebody already face this issue and came up with a good / alternative solution how to handle this?

Test Add-In source code is available here: [OneDrive Link](https://1drv.ms/u/s!An1GkEwX73Cwk-VbNqjmoqGi6A0wiA?e=48VFSu)

Comment: I suggest you submit your feedback on https://officespdev.uservoice.com/

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I planned to open an MS Case anyway in case that I won't find any solution here.